# Event listeners, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, events, listener

How do I make new content show in my DOM everytime I click a nav link and delete the old one. I get the content one after another when clicking, I want to delete the old one, and show the one I clicked and so on.
I'm using an array from a database.
This is the code:

```
$(dataItems).on('click', 'li a', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  let id = $(this).attr('data-code'); // sort them by their data-code

  const childrenItems = []; // push the sorted array items from db to this array
  for (let i = 0; i < Assortments.length; i++) { // This is the array from DB
    if (Assortments[i].AssortimentParentID == id) {
      childrenItems.push(Assortments[i].Name);
    }
  }

  //draw html table
  let perrow = 3, // 3 items per row
       count = 0, // flag for current cell
       table = document.createElement("table"),
       row = table.insertRow();

  for (let i of childrenItems) {
    let cell = row.insertCell();
    cell.innerHTML = i;

    count++;
    if (count%perrow == 0) {
      row = table.insertRow();
    }
  }
  document.querySelector(".deposit-container").appendChild(table);


})
```

prnt.sc/rdnavd - this is how it looks, as you can see there's 2 tables, I clicked on 2 different categories, I want when clicking a category to show only one table and delete the other clicked before.

Comment: I didn't get the why this kind of code do you need. If you need to add a new event listener for new elements which are just added to DOM. Just define the listener like  `$('body').on('click', '#your-selector', function) `. If you still need to make it as you want. You can do your need with `MutationObserver`

Comment: https://prnt.sc/rdnavd - this is how it looks, as you can see there's 2 tables, I clicked on 2 different categories, I want when clicking a category to show only one table and delete the other clicked before.

Comment: kindly provide a working example of jsFiddle or codepen. It would be easier to find a solution then.

Comment: The code is like 400 lines long, don't think I can do that. Only thing I could provide is the code above. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this line: 
`document.querySelector(".deposit-container").appendChild(table);` 
try replacing `appendChild` to `innerHTML`. Append will just keep on adding the element instead of replacing it. 
Revised line: 
`document.querySelector(".deposit-container").innerHTML = table;`

**EDIT:**

If the above didn’t work. Try resetting the child node.

Replace `document.querySelector(".deposit-container").appendChild(table);`  with the below:

```
let parent = document.querySelector(".deposit-container");

while(parent.firstChild){
  parent.removeChild(parent.firstChild);
}

parent.appendChild(table);
```

Let me know if this helps...

Comment: I get [object HTMLTableElement] in my DOM. Doesn't seem to work. Thanks!

Comment: @Dipzera sorry i was on my phone, if the above didn’t work you could try removing the child `removeChild()` of the node before re-appending the table.

Comment: like before creating the table? or just before the:
`document.querySelector(".deposit-container").appendChild(table);` ?

Comment: @Dipzera yes right before the line with the `appendChild()`

Comment: `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.` - I get this error in console.

Comment: It worked, thanks! That's what I needed! Thanks a  lot!